# I can't install scipy on my system. It's returning (Preparing wheel metadata ... error) error

Tags: python, pip, scipy

```
python -m pip install scipy
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-1.10.1.tar.gz (42.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\krishna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' 'C:\Users\krishna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\krishna\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpxethxusy'
         cwd: C:\Users\krishna\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1wgjtick\scipy_fac0ca1251214cdeafaad46bb44ff214
    Complete output (21 lines):
    + meson setup --prefix=C:\Users\krishna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32 C:\Users\krishna\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1wgjtick\scipy_fac0ca1251214cdeafaad46bb44ff214 C:\Users\krishna\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1wgjtick\scipy_fac0ca1251214cdeafaad46bb44ff214\.mesonpy-vy7qkgk8\build --native-file=C:\Users\krishna\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1wgjtick\scipy_fac0ca1251214cdeafaad46bb44ff214\.mesonpy-native-file.ini -Ddebug=false -Doptimization=2
    The Meson build system
    Version: 1.3.1
    Source dir: C:\Users\krishna\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1wgjtick\scipy_fac0ca1251214cdeafaad46bb44ff214
    Build dir: C:\Users\krishna\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1wgjtick\scipy_fac0ca1251214cdeafaad46bb44ff214\.mesonpy-vy7qkgk8\build
    Build type: native build
    Project name: SciPy
    Project version: 1.10.1
    WARNING: Failed to activate VS environment: Could not parse vswhere.exe output

    ..\..\meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['icl'], ['cl'], ['cc'], ['gcc'], ['clang'], ['clang-cl'], ['pgcc']]
    The following exception(s) were encountered:
    Running `icl ""` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
    Running `cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
    Running `cc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
    Running `gcc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
    Running `clang --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
    Running `clang-cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
    Running `pgcc --version` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

    A full log can be found at C:\Users\krishna\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1wgjtick\scipy_fac0ca1251214cdeafaad46bb44ff214\.mesonpy-vy7qkgk8\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
    ----------------------------------------
```

Was trying to install scipy, but it's not installing.

Comment: I found another question with the same error so I marked this as a duplicate, but of course, it's possible that your root cause is different. If so, please [edit] to provide more details and help us see what the actual problem is. (It's likely a duplicate of _another_ similar question then, but of course, it's always possible that you have found a completely novel bug.)